# Starting an application (on button click) that opens a .txt file and puts the output to another .txt file

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I have a good working console application that opens a `.txt` file and puts its output by creating another `.txt` file.

However when I try to use `Process.Start` my application (at button click, through VB) it crashes.
I have tried several dozen code combinations and isolated the problem:

It seems that if my console application has to open or has anything to do with external files, then it crashes. 
I can easily use `Process.Start` in an application that uses no external data.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your console application rather than in the way it's being called. If the application actually starts and executes, it's unlikely that your process start parameters are the problem. Is it possible that the application just can't find the files it's looking for? Have you tried absolute path names? Without seeing some code, we can't provide very much help.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't thought about absolute path. Form works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the external application has the rights to modify files.

You can add a `ProcessStartInfo` to your `Process` before the `Start` :

```
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processInfo.FileName = command;
    processInfo.Arguments = parameters;
    processInfo.UserName = "username";
    processInfo.Password = password;
    processInfo.Domain = "myDomain";
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

    Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This should run the process as admin and make sure the process has the right to modify the files.

Also, if you could give the output for the crash that would be very helpful in solving your issue.